# CSS how to get floated left text to wrap?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is there a way I can get all `<li>` elements to fit in one line to the width of the window (and the text wraps accordingly?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>laksdjf laksdj flasdj fladjs flaksd</li>
    <li>laksdjf laksdj </li>
    <li>laksdjf laksdj flasdj fladjs flaksd fladjs flaksd</li>
    <li>laksdjf laksdj flasdj fladjs flaksd</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
}

ul li {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        padding: 0 30px;
        float:left;
}
```

The width of the `li` should be relative to the amount of text they have in it. If I put a fixed size on it, then the longer text ones are too squeezed.

http://jsfiddle.net/5gP3b/

Comment: If you want to make a dynamic size for your li you have to use javascript

Comment: Only with CSS ? I'm not sure, but if there's a solution it probably resides in using `display:table` and/or `display:table-cell`. But then you might aswell use a table :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the display `table` and `table-cell` property to achieve it: http://jsfiddle.net/5gP3b/1/

Notice that this display property do not work on Internet Explorer 6 & 7 ...

Comment: That worked. Is there any other solution that would work for IE 7 as well?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You should provide a fallback using javascript for IE7 by calculating and setting the width of each column (and using `float: left`)